# Why isn't my Used + Avail equalling the total space in my partition?

Tags: partitioning, external-hdd, disk, disk-usage

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.  I have purchased an additional partition in my hosting environment hta tis supposedly 100 GB.  However, when I check the space of that partition, I see something odd

```
myuser@myproject:~$ df -h /mnt/volume-nyc1-01/
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda         99G   93G  730M 100% /mnt/volume-nyc1-01
```

Shouldn't the Used + Avail equal the total size?  If not, how do I figure out where the rest of the space is getting used?

Answer (score 0):

Two hypotheses:

- The difference between GB and GiB: the xB prefix are power of 10, while the xiB prefixes are power of 2^10 (1024). So, 1 KiB = 1.024 KB, etc ... and 1GiB = (1.024^3) GB
- You need also to know that some "emergency" space is reserved for root. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why

Best regards.