# Used and available df values don't add up to the correct size

Tags: disk-usage, df

I just did a `df` to check the disk usage on a new 16.04 installation and noticed the following result.  The used and available on `/dev/sda2` don't add up to the partition size.  Even if I do `836120968-14720428-778903724`, the result doesn't seem to match others.  Can anyone help me interpret why the available is much less than total - used?

FYI, I partitioned a 1TB disk fully into 4 partitions sda1-4.  I also disabled the swap since I have enough memory and don't want the swapfile on the SSD.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            32800684        0  32800684   0% /dev
tmpfs            6565404     9840   6555564   1% /run
/dev/sda2      836120968 14720428 778903724   2% /
tmpfs           32827012     8240  32818772   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           32827012        0  32827012   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1         523248     4756    518492   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda3       29282528    24912  29257616   1% /fat32
/dev/sda4       97305376       32  97305344   1% /ntfs
tmpfs            6565404       40   6565364   1% /run/user/1001
```

Comment: Possibly related: [Why isn't my Used + Avail equalling the total space in my partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903677/why-isnt-my-used-avail-equalling-the-total-space-in-my-partition)

Answer (score 0):

`Used` and `Available` are not added up to the `1K-blocks` because the `Available` excludes the blocks reserved by root.

Reference:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179274/what-does-1k-blocks-column-mean-in-the-output-of-df

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Df_(Unix)